# What does the shortcut JE used in tennis drawsheets mean?

Tags: terminology, tennis

I have noticed a shortcut JE in drawsheets of some tennis tournaments. For example, it is used [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Dow_Corning_Tennis_Classic_%E2%80%93_Singles) (for Taylor Towsend) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_The_Oaks_Club_Challenger_%E2%80%93_Singles) (for Kateřina Siniaková).

What does this shortcut mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut JE stands for *Junior Exempt*.

Looking at the main article of both given example:

We can find the meaning of JE in [Other entrants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Dow_Corning_Tennis_Classic#Other_entrants)

> The following player received entry through **Junior Exempt**:
>
> - Taylor Townsend

For [Kateřina Siniaková](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_The_Oaks_Club_Challenger#Other_entrants)

> The following player received entry by a **Junior Exempt**:
>
> - Kateřina Siniaková

Comment: I'll just add a link to an explanation of the term Junior Exempt from ITF website: http://www.itftennis.com/juniors/players/junior-exempt.aspx Thanks a lot for your answer!